ERROR:yfinance:AAL: Period '60d' is invalid, must be one of ['1d', '5d', '1mo', '3mo', '6mo', '1y', '2y', '5y', '10y', 'ytd', 'max']
I am trying to download 15 min stock data from yfinance. This is the function I use / used to download the data. The commented line is another method to download data, but because it didn't work this morning I tried the other line of code.
import yfinance as yf
import pandas as pd

def download_data(ticker):
    period="60d"
    interval = "15m"
    # data = yf.download(ticker, period=period, interval=interval)
    data = yf.Ticker(ticker).history(interval=interval, period=period)
    data = calculate_technical_indicators(data)
    data = tomorrow(data, -5)
    data.dropna(inplace=True)
    return data

But I am getting this error:
ERROR:yfinance:AAL: Period '60d' is invalid, must be one of ['1d', '5d', '1mo', '3mo', '6mo', '1y', '2y', '5y', '10y', 'ytd', 'max']

I have been using this function for the last couple of months. And since this morning I can't seem to get 60 days worth of data.

I figured that just getting the start and end dates within a 60 day window and adding to the download function is an easy fix.
def get_dates(period):
    utc = datetime.datetime.now(pytz.utc)
    tz = pytz.timezone("US/Eastern")
    ny = utc.astimezone(tz)
    ny_datetime_index = DatetimeIndex([ny])
    today = ny_datetime_index[0]
    start_date = today - datetime.timedelta(days=period)
    return today, start_date

def download_data(ticker, period):
    period = period
    interval = "15m"
    end, start = get_dates(period)
    data = yf.Ticker(ticker).history(interval=interval, start=start, end=end)
    data = tomorrow(data)
    data = calculate_technical_indicators(data)
    data.dropna(inplace=True)
    return data


Please show how you changed the code.

@Barmar I edited the answer to have the changed code

I encountered the same issue on my laptop, while my desktop PC allows me to use periods such as '18mo', '60d' etc.
I managed to resolve this issue by reverting to an older version of yfinance, version 0.2.17.
pip uninstall yfinance
...
pip install yfinance==0.2.17

Do mind that the older version could lack some features you use in your code, but assuming you've been using an older version before running into this issue, I find that unlikely.
